# How do I pass retrieve data from the selected product in the popup window and display it in the table

Tags: javascript, php

How do I pass the retrieve data from the selected product in the popup window and display it in the table.
The data comes from the database, I want to display the product name and its details in the table.

This is the table looks like:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvRMJ.png)

This will be the popup window after I clicked the add product button in the table:
[Popup Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkWC5.png)

Code:

```
<table id="data_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Component</th>
                    <th class="status-column1">Product</th>
                    <th class="status-column">Details</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="no-border-right">Processor</td>
                    <td class="no-border-right no-border-left" id="selectedProductCell"></td>
                    <td class="no-border-right no-border-left" id="selectedProductDetailCell"><a href="#"><button
                                onclick='openPopup()' class="addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Product</button></a></td>
                    <td class="no-border-left"><button class="removeButton" style="display: none;">Remove</button></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="productPopup" style="display: none;">
            <?php
            // Retrieve CPU products and details from the database and populate the popup content
            $query = "SELECT * FROM cpu_db";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            $cpuProducts = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $details = $row['brand'] . ' ' . $row['c_speed'] . ' ' . $row['cores'] . ' ' . $row['mem_supp'];
                $cpuProducts[] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'details' => $details);
            }

            // Convert the PHP array to a JavaScript array for use in the openPopup function
            $cpuProductsJSON = json_encode($cpuProducts);
            ?>
            <script>
                var cpuProducts = <?php echo $cpuProductsJSON; ?>;
            </script>
        </div>
        <script>
            let selectedProductName = '';
            let selectedProductDetails = '';

            function showPopup(html) {
                var popupWindow = window.open("", "Popup", "width=600,height=400,left=" + (screen.width - 600) / 2 + ",top=" + (screen.height - 400) / 2);
                popupWindow.document.write(html);
                popupWindow.document.close();
                var contentHeight = popupWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
                popupWindow.resizeTo(700, contentHeight + 50);
            }

            function openPopup() {
                var popupHTML = "<div style='font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-align: center;'>";
                popupHTML += "<h2>Select a CPU Product</h2>";

                popupHTML += "<table>"; // Start the table

                for (const product of cpuProducts) {
                    // Add a row for each product with CPU name and details
                    popupHTML += "<tr>";
                    popupHTML += "<td>" + product.name + "</td>"; // Display CPU name
                    popupHTML += "<td>" + product.details + "</td>"; // Display CPU details
                    popupHTML += "<td><button onclick='selectProduct(\"" + product.name + "\", \"" + product.details + "\")'>Add</button></td>"; // Add button
                    popupHTML += "</tr>";
                }

                popupHTML += "</table>"; // End the table

                popupHTML += "</div>";

                showPopup(popupHTML);
            }

            function selectProduct(productName, productDetails) {
                selectedProductName = productName; // Store the selected product name
                selectedProductDetails = productDetails;

                // Hide the popup
                const popup = document.getElementById('productPopup');
                popup.style.display = 'none';

                // Update the previous table row with the selected product name
                const productCell = document.querySelector('.no-border-right');
                productCell.textContent = 'Processor'; // Set the label

                const productNameCell = document.querySelector('#selectedProductCell');
                productNameCell.textContent = selectedProductName;

                // Show the Remove button
                const removeButton = document.querySelector('.removeButton');
                removeButton.style.display = 'inline';

                // Update the third cell with the selected product details
                const detailsCell = document.querySelector('#selectedProductDetailCell');
                detailsCell.textContent = selectedProductDetails;

                // Make an AJAX call to fetch data from the server
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "view_cpu_details.php", // Replace with the correct file path
                    data: {
                        product_name: selectedProductName
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Update the selected product details
                        selectedProductDetails = response.details;

                        // Update the details cell in your table
                        detailsCell.textContent = selectedProductDetails;
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

This is the view_cpu_details.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

if (isset($_GET['product_name'])) {
    $product_name = $_GET['product_name'];

    // Query to retrieve CPU details based on the product name
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cpu_db WHERE name = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $product_name);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $cpu_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        // Return the CPU details as JSON response
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($cpu_details);
    } else {
        echo "CPU details not found.";
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
} else {
    echo "Product name not provided.";
}
?>
```

This is the output I want to achieve after  I select a product from the popup window:
[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu6wn.png)

Comment: So what problem you are facing?

Comment: Why do you need an ajax call? Why don't you populate the table with PHP in the backend?

Comment: @CodeThing the data are not displaying in the table cell after clicking the add in the popup window

Comment: @needsHelp You should consider using modal popup. You are currently opening a new browser window. So your JS code will not work as expected.